# ¿Cómo puedo llamar el valor de mi checkbox del formulario?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms

He puesto en forms.py un checkbox, pero luego he probado de varias formas llamarlo en la función, pero no me coge el valor:

```
class Form(forms.ModelForm):
    prueba= forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput(), required=False, label='Prueba', initial=False)

    def prueba(self):
        if self.fields['prueba'] is False: # NO FUNCIONA SIEMPTRE ENTRA EN EL ELSE

        # if self.cleaned_data['prueba'] is False:
            print("es falso")
        else:
            print("es simulacro")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres acceder al valor una ves que se envió el formulario lo puedes hacer desde el método clean() o desde el método clean_campo(), este ultimo se ejecuta después del método clean().

Haciéndolo desde el método clean seria así:

```
class Form(forms.ModelForm):
    
  prueba= forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput(), required=False, label='Prueba', initial=False)

  def clean(self):
    # opcion 1
    # con metodo clean
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    prueba = cleaned_data.get('prueba')

    if prueba is False:
      print('es falso')
    else:
      print('es simulacro')

    return cleaned_data

  def clean_prueba(self):
    # Opcion 2
    # con el clean del campo
    prueba = self.cleaned_data.get('prueba')

    if prueba is False:
      print('es falso')
    else:
      print('es simulacro')

    return prueba
```

Si quisieras acceder a otros valores dentro del metodo clean_campo() simplemente es necesario ver si se tiene el valor dentro de cleaned_data, lo puedes hacer de esta manera.

```
class Form(forms.ModelForm):
    
  prueba= forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput(), required=False, label='Prueba', initial=False)

  def clean_prueba(self):
    # Acceder a varios valores dentro del clean del campo prueba
    prueba = self.cleaned_data.get('prueba')
    fecha_desde = self.cleaned_data.get('fecha_desde')
    fecha_hasta = self.cleaned_data.get('fecha_desde')

    if prueba is False:
      print('es falso')
    else:
      print('es simulacro')

    print('fecha_desde', fecha_desde)
    print('fecha_hasta', fecha_hasta)

    # Solo se regresa el valor del campo prueba o puedes regresar algun valor modificado mientras coincida con el tipo del campo prueba
    return prueba
```

Comment: si sé que se puede hacer desde clean, pero también se puede hacer desde la otra aunque no se cómo. Por ejem esto funciona pero al replicarlo con lo que quiero no me ha ido bien:


`def date_is_later(self, date_control):
        d = self.cleaned_data.get(date_control)
        if d and d > now().date():
            raise ValidationError(_('Date {} has a later date').format(self.fields[date_control].label))
        return d

    def clean_fecha_desde(self):
        return self.date_is_later('f_desde')

    def clean_fecha_hasta(self):
        return self.date_is_later('f_hasta')`

Comment: Esto te funciona por que llamas a tu función date_is_later() dentro del clean del campo fecha_desde y fecha_hasta , si así es como lo quieres, solo necesitas poner la funcion clean del campo prueba. Actualizo mi respuesta. Solo recuerda que los clean_campo() son llamados despues del clean().

Comment: Muchas gracias, si funciona. Pero una duda más y soy consciente de que soy un poco pesado.
Si yo quiero dentro de la misma función quiero 3 elementos del form "fecha_desde , fecha_hasta y prueba" ¿Cómo se llamaría la función? (sin contar la de def clean(self))
He probado con def clean_prueba_fecha_desde_fecha_hasta(self) y también con def prueba__fecha_desde__fecha_hasta(self) pero ninguno me va

Comment: No te preocupes lo importante es resolver las dudas, te completo la respuesta a ver si esto te sirve. Puedes acceder a el valor de otros campos dentro del campo clean_campo(). Si te llega a funcionar la respuesta la puedes marcar como aceptada por si alguien mas tiene la misma duda.